# Anyone having experience with DominoTomcatSSO project?

Tags: lotus-domino

Is there anyone having experience with DominoTomcatSSO project? (see here http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=DominoTomcatSSO )

I'm running Tomcat 6.0.37 and Domino 9 server. I have configured everything and can't see any error on Domino console. When I try to login in my Tomcat application and mistype the password, Domino and Tomcat correctly report, that username/password is incorrect so things are working fine. But when I type the correct password, I'm getting an error in my Tomcat application as below. When I look into my browser cookies, the LtpaToken is there but somehow cannot be used when creating a Notes Session as in error message. Any hint what can be wrong here?

```
NotesException - 4616 Cookie is invalid
NotesException: Cookie is invalid
        at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHelper.read(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHolder._read(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.domino.corba._IObjectServerStub.createSessionWithCookie(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.domino.cso.Session.initSession(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.domino.cso.Session.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.domino.cso.Session.createSession(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSessionC(Unknown Source)
        at lotus.domino.NotesFactory.createSession(Unknown Source)
        at com.automatedlogic.domino.sso.DominoBridge.openDominoSession(DominoBridge.java:84)
        at com.automatedlogic.domino.sso.DominoBridge.openDominoSession(DominoBridge.java:68)
        at com.automatedlogic.domino.sso.DominoUserProfile.refresh(DominoUserProfile.java:180)
        at com.automatedlogic.domino.sso.DominoLoginFilter.doFilter(DominoLoginFilter.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:879)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1760)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found a problem, see URL below. I have updated the InternetSite configuration (descriptive name) based on point 1 from the answer in URL below.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=899&uid=swg21202709

Comment: +1 nice find :-) you should also flag your question as answered